# appending a class to list results in appending str error python

Tags: python, append

So I my program has a class with a persons name. I am trying to have the program read it off from a input file and then read it and arrange it into classes. While I am trying to appened the class to a list. It gives me this error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
I have used this code before to do the same similar thing, but without reading from a file. I was wondering what was happening to cause this error.
Here is my code:

```
class person:
def __init__(self, FName, FLast,age ):
    self.FName=FName
    self.FLast=FLast
    self.age=age


from sys import argv

script = argv
filename = raw_input('enter filename: ')
txt = open(filename, 'r+')
count = 0


i = 2
lines = txt.readlines()
z=lines[0]
a=lines[1]
r=lines[2]
hi=person(z,a,r)
a=[hi]

while i != -1:
  try:
    z=lines[i]
    a=lines[i+1]
    r=lines[i+2]
    i = i + 3
    hi=person(z,a,r)
    a.append[hi]
except IndexError:
    i = -1
```

Comment: `append()` not `append[]`

Comment: The file looks something like this:

Comment: first line: First name, second line: second name, third line: age, I have a total of three people like this so the file overall is 9 lines long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues in your code -

1. `a.append[hi]` - This is not how you append, append is a function, you have to call it passing it the value to append as parameter.
2. You are defining `a` as a string in the line - `a=lines[i+1]` - Then you are trying to append to it.

You may want to create a new list outside the `while` , and then keep appending to it.

Example -

```
classlist = []
while i != -1:
  try:
    z=lines[i]
    a=lines[i+1]
    r=lines[i+2]
    i = i + 3
    hi=person(z,a,r)
    classlist.append(hi)
except IndexError:
    i = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact you are getting only one element from the list .Then list will return the element as it's original type

```
class person:
    def __init__(self, FName, FLast,age ):
        self.FName=FName
        self.FLast=FLast
        self.age=age


from sys import argv

script = argv
filename = raw_input('enter filename: ')
txt = open(filename, 'r+')
count = 0


i = 2
lines = txt.readlines()
z=lines[0]
a=lines[1]
r=lines[2]
hi=person(z,a,r)
a=[hi]

while i != -1:
    try:
        z=lines[i]
        a=list(lines[i+1]) #converting it to list
        r=lines[i+2]
        i = i + 3
        hi=person(z,a,r)
        a.append(hi) #append is a method so ()
    except IndexError:
        i = -1
```